# DynamoDB - TransactWrite, how to do If Else condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

An example, a table with a column `counter` with only 1 row. I want to update this row's counter value based on its current value.

Say if `counter` is >= 10, set it to 0, otherwise `counter++`. How to achieve this `if else` clause in `TransactWrite`?

I can't have two actions in one transaction because Documentation states that it does not allow more than 1 action on the same item.

And of course, the reason I use `TransactWrite` is because there will be multiple lambda doing this task in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it in one request, transactional or otherwise.

You can get the item, decide what to do, and then update the item in a second request accordingly. You’ll want to keep a version number or timestamp attribute to make sure the item hasn’t changed between the read and write, and use a condition expression to fail if it has.

That’s a common idiom:
https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-locking/

Comment: So essentially transactional approach won't work in this situation and the only solution is to do optimistic locking?

Comment: Assuming you need the behavior as described.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it the way you like, because if/else is not supported in transactions. There is however a simpler solution.

Just Update the item and increment the counter. Whenever you read the value, you take the counter value modulo 10, and you get the desired behavior, e.g. `123 % 10 = 3` or `10 % 10 = 0`.

Comment: How do I be able to tell when to %10 and when to +1 though?

Comment: You do that when you read the counter value to use it. Your data access layer can do the mod 10, in DynamoDB the value will only increase.

Comment: The issue is that I need the read + write happen in the same transaction so my multiple lambda / processes do the read + write won't cause race condition.

Comment: The counter increment in UpdateItem is ACID compliant. Just tell the API call to return the updated item (it can do that) and read the counter value mod 10. No problem with race conditions here :-) - You only need transactions if you want ACID across multiple items.